# Dovecot: removes my mail automatically

Tags: dovecot

I noticed that dovecot removes my mails automatically after 30 days. This is undesired behaviour for me, but I have no idea how to change this.

I checked autoexpunge configuration, but it is disabled:

```
# doveconf | grep expunge
autoexpunge = 0
autoexpunge_max_mails = 0
autoexpunge = 0
autoexpunge_max_mails = 0
autoexpunge = 0
autoexpunge_max_mails = 0
autoexpunge = 0
autoexpunge_max_mails = 0
autoexpunge = 0
autoexpunge_max_mails = 0
```

I looked through the configuration files carefully, but found no place where such setting could be set. Could you please help me find the reason, why email gets deleted and how to fix that.

I use debian stretch with dovecot + postfix + postgres with mostly default configuration.

UPDATE:

I figured out that the reason for emails to disappear is `/etc/cron.daily/sa-learn` script that has following excerpt:

```sh
MAILDIR=/home/mailboxes/maildir/
USERS=$(ls /home/mailboxes/maildir/ | grep -v $SPAMTRAP)
SPAM=".Junk"

# ...

echo Sync SA base >> $log 2>&1
sa-learn --sync >> $log 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        for user in $USERS ; do
                maildir=$MAILDIR/$user
                echo "deleting spam for $u older than $cleanafter" >> $log 2>&1
                find $maildir -type f -mtime +$cleanafter -exec rm {} \;
        done
else
        echo "sa-learn wasn't able to sync. Something is broken. Skipping spam cleanup"
fi
```

I'm not sure where does `sa-learn` script came from, but it seems that this behavior is deeply flaw.

Comment: Why do you believe that Dovecot is doing it, rather than your email client?

Comment: I use the same client for multiple servers and also multiple accounts on this server use different clients.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really dovecot, you should see this in logs. Otherwise, check whether it is not your mail client. Raise the verbosity of logs and check them when you notice mails missing. Here is the proper documentation: https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/logging/

And of course - don't hesitate to share your findings.